# Use tc and xdp programs to broker services in docker containers

Tags: docker, tcp, ip, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I have a web service in my ubuntu container bound to an address of **172.17.0.2:8080**. The network address of my host is **172.16.0.240**, and the ip address of another device is **172.16.0.198**.

Access **172.16.0.240:9999** and route the destination ip and mac of the packet to the ubuntu container through the xdp program. After the web service in the container responds, use the tc exit program to change the source ip, port, and mac, but when establishing the tcp connection, The connection was reset by the client. I don't know how a packet is generated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcj83.png)
docker0 is network bridge
docker0: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFVTU.png)
eth0 is network card in docker
eth0:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4jMj.png)
wlp0s20f3 Is the physical network card of my host
wlp0s20f3: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW4hy.png)
**first:**
I used the xdp program to change the destination ip and destination mac of the data packet accessed by the client into the ip and mac of the eth network adapter in the container, and then forwarded the data packet to the docker0 network adapter, whose iface.index was 5.

```
        if (tcp->dest == bpf_htons(9999) && iph->daddr == bpf_htonl(0xac1000f0)) {
            tcp->dest = bpf_htons(8080);
            iph->daddr = bpf_htonl(0xAC110002);
            eth->h_dest[0] = 2;
            eth->h_dest[1] = 66;
            eth->h_dest[2] = -84;
            eth->h_dest[3] = 17;
            eth->h_dest[4] = 0;
            eth->h_dest[5] = 2;
            iph->check = ipv4_csum(iph);
            return bpf_redirect(5, 0);
        }
```

**second:**
the response packet of the service in the container is changed into the related data of wlp0s20f3 network adapter through tc program, and then sent out to the client, but in the tcp connection stage, the connection is reset by the server.

Because of the emergence of a packet is not tc program modification right, can see I do the debug information in the/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe. I judge that all packets with port 8080 and ip 172.17.0.2 will be modified. However, there is a packet with ip 172.16.0.240. I do not know how it is generated.
**debug info at /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe:**

```
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.289402: bpf_trace_printk: source: 8080, target: 47018, src: ac110002
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.289415: bpf_trace_printk: 1
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.289416: bpf_trace_printk: 2
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.315978: bpf_trace_printk: source: 8080, target: 47018, src: ac1000f0
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.315991: bpf_trace_printk: 1
            main-12886   [007] D.s3.  3224.316547: bpf_trace_printk: source: 8080, target: 47018, src: ac1000f0
            main-12886   [007] D.s3.  3224.316557: bpf_trace_printk: 1
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.637523: bpf_trace_printk: source: 8080, target: 47018, src: ac110002
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.637535: bpf_trace_printk: 1
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.637537: bpf_trace_printk: 2
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.916243: bpf_trace_printk: source: 8080, target: 47018, src: ac110002
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.916255: bpf_trace_printk: 1
 irq/147-iwlwifi-588     [003] D.s3.  3224.916257: bpf_trace_printk: 2
```

**how I debug:**

```
        bpf_printk("source: %d, target: %d, src: %2x", bpf_ntohs(tcp->source), bpf_ntohs(tcp->dest), bpf_ntohl(iph->saddr));
        bpf_printk("1");
        if (tcp->source == bpf_htons(8080) || iph->saddr == bpf_htonl(0xAC110002)) {
            tcp->source = bpf_htons(9999);
            iph->saddr = bpf_htonl(0xac1000f0);
            eth->h_source[0] = xx;
            eth->h_source[1] = xx;
            eth->h_source[2] = xx;
            eth->h_source[3] = 70;
            eth->h_source[4] = 58;
            eth->h_source[5] = 57;
            iph->check = ipv4_csum(iph);
            bpf_printk("2");
        }
```

Comment: What would be useful to see is the packet flow (tcpdump?) on the client's side. If the client sends a TCP RST, it likely means that your reverse DNAT or reverse SNAT are broken.

Comment: I added three screenshots of packet capture, including wireshark screenshots of the container network card, container bridge and host physical network card。